# struct pointer array issue

Tags: c, struct

```
typedef struct ListNode *Position;
typedef struct Position List; 
typedef struct HashTbl *HashTable;

struct ListNode{
    int Element;
};

struct HashTbl{
    int TableSize;
    List* TheLists;
};

int main(){
    int size = 5;
    HashTable hashTable = malloc(sizeof(struct HashTbl));
    hashTable->TheLists = (List*)malloc(sizeof(List*)*size);
    //i want to approach Element of ListNode
    for(int i=0 ; i<size ; i++){
        hashTable->TheLists[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
        //at [i] : Subscript of pointer to incomplete type 'List' 
    }
}
```

How can I approach Element of ListNode?
I think 'TheList' is an array of pointer. So I tried to allocate and approach it.
but at hashTable->TheLists**[**i] the compiler says

```
Subscript of pointer to incomplete type 'List'.
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: This sends me straight to `typedef` hell. But `hashTable->TheLists = (List*)malloc(sizeof(List*)*size);` should be something like `hashTable->TheLists = malloc(sizeof(List)*size);`, or better yet `hashTable->TheLists = malloc(sizeof(*(hashTable->TheLists))*size);`. `List*` is a pointer to `List`, you need to allocate the size of a `List` object. `sizeof(List*`)` is the size of a pointer, which will be 4 or 8 depending on your architecture.

Comment: If this is supposed to be a complete program, you are missing to declare `struct Position`. That makes `List` incomplete.

Comment: @yano +1 for "typedef hell"  Drop the typedefs.  They are not clarifying anything, but just obscuring the names.  Use typedefs for function types.  There is absolutely no reason to use them just to avoid typing `struct` now and then.